# how do I extract data from links inside a webpage and then add them to already exists csv file?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, extract

I was able to extract the data in a table in Wikipedia page into a csv file but what I want to do further is to access some links inside this table. so I have a column in the table that has names of some countries and I want to access each link, extract some of its data and add it to the already generated csv file that has already crawled attributes.

[a list of the countries I want to extract some of its data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exMUh.png)

the code I already wrote using beautifulsoup:

```
rows= country_names.find_all('tr')

columns = [re.sub('(\[[a-zA-Z\d]*\])+\n','',v.text).strip() for v in rows[0].find_all('th')]

print(columns)
```

```
for i in range(1, len(rows)):
    tds=rows[i].find_all('td')
    if len(tds) == 4:
        values= [tds[0].text, tds[1].text, '', td[2].text,tds[3].text]
    else:
        values = [re.sub('\xa0sq\xa0mi','',td.text).replace('\n','').replace('\xa0km2','').replace('\u200e','') for td in tds]
    #print(values)
    df = df.append(pd.Series(values, index=columns), ignore_index=True)
```

these how I extracted the rows and the columns and I used

```
for link in soup.find_all ('a', href=True):
   
    
    links= link.find('table', class_= 'wikitable sortable')
```

to extract all the links in the table but I cannot  specify the country name column and extract the data in each country link.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just one web page then you might as well do it manually.

If it is going to be an ongoing project of scraping many different web pages then you may want to use scrapy.  There is a learning curve, but it is python based and can traverse pages in a website, extracting and putting data where you want it.

Comment: I mean I should go over all countries and extract data from each link of each country and it’s really difficult to go over each country individually